# Importing data from text to SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, text, ssms

To begin with, my source data are excel spreadsheets. From there, I save them as .csv's and then open them in Notepad ++ and then save them as .txt files. When I do so, I get the following error

Warning 0x802092a2 Data Flow Task 1; Truncation may occur due to inserting data from data flow column "Xyz" with a length of 50 to database column "Xyz" with a length of 2.

This error shows up for all of the character fields or fields in which the values are non-numeric and have no decimals. I tried a trick where I bring it from the text file into access and then export it as a text file to no avail.

Any Ideas or Thoughts? This is my first endeavor into SQL so pardon my naivete.

Comment: If you want to store 50 characters into a column, then that column should be declared to have a length of at least 50.

Comment: I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2014 edition.

Comment: For example, the value in excel is 32, I save it as a .csv and then to text and in the text file, it reads 32. Both versions are only 2 characters in length.

Comment: Why all the work to get to a .txt file?  You can directly import from an Excel sheet with SSMS.

Comment: I am really new to this and when I attempted to import from excel, the errors were far greater than with the text file.

Answer (score 0):

FYI you can save directly to TXT via Excel, but saving as CSV shouldn't be a problem in either case.

First off, I'm making a few assumptions here based on my experience. I assume you are using the "Flat File Source" option when you are using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard.

If that's the case, you want to click on the left hand side and go to the Advanced tab on the left side and then go to each column individually and change their data types (most likely to string, but if you know you only have integer values in a column you can use a data type that fits) then the outputcolumnwidth to a number higher than your maximum data size in each column.

If you are creating a table via the wizard, you may need to change the field types when you get to that part of the wizard. If you are using an existing SQL table... things are a bit trickier and you will need to give us some more info about what you are doing before we can give you a solid answer.

Basically, you want your source column definitions to match your target columns as closely as you can get. If you are inserting to an existing table you may need to massage your data first in Excel to fit your target column types.

Comment: I have already created a table. For this question, I will focus on one field type. When I get it out of my manual, it reads numeric (9,2) as the field type. So that tells me 9 to the left and 2 to the right of the decimal.

Comment: I have already created a table. For this question, I will focus on one field type. When I get it out of my manual, it reads numeric (9,2) as the field type. So that tells me 9 to the left and 2 to the right of the decimal.

So now I am importing the "Flat File Source". I went to "Advanced" on the left and am at the field in question. I choose Decimal. Is datascale where I would tell it be (9,2) or is there another way?

Comment: Use Numeric and then choose 9 for precision and 2 for scale if you want to be more accurate. Decimal doesn't allow for precision. File data types are a bit weird. Also, it is critical that the table columns you are inserting data into can accept this data. The target column must also be decimal(9,2).